# How do I pass an integer value to another class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Here is my code:

**secondClass.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) int number;
```

**secondClass.m**

```
@synthesize number;


  //positioning object in x position of first class

  object.center = CGPointMake(number, object.center.y);


  NSLog(@"%d",number);
```

**first class.m**

```
#import "secondClass.h"
secondClass *second = [secondClass alloc];
second.number = 15;
```

I used NSLog to see what is happening. In the first class, the value of the second number is 15. When I used NSLog to see it's value in the second class, it comes up as 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you synthesize the number in .m file?

Comment: You're only allocating `secondClass`, never `initializing` it.

Comment: You should really name your classes according to Apple's guidelines `XXSecondClass`.

Comment: i did.. sorry mistake when copying code.

Comment: @property (nonatomic,assign) int number;

Comment: Tried now also with assign. Still no luck here.

Comment: i habe edited the code again.

Comment: which method does have this line: `object.center = CGPointMake(number, object.center.y);`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just have a typo in your description but try:

```
secondClass *second = [[secondClass alloc] init];  
second.number = 15;  
NSlog(@"number is:%d",number);
```

Comment: tried with initializing it now.. but still result is the same. Still got 0 in secondClass.m output.

Comment: Can you post your actual code (since the NSLog is missing, and some code posted here is incorrect). Consider this: Your code doesn't do what you want it to do. So don't keep code away from us because you assume it is correct. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to synthesize your number in secondClass.m

```
@synthesize number;
```

and add the **init** in your secondClass declaration

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Find a similar case. The thing is that I'm using segue for transition from one view controller to another. I solved out problem with method prepareForSegue. Here is the code I was searching:

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NextView"]){
    secondClass *second = (secondClass *)segue.destinationViewController;
    second.number = object.center.x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (readwrite) int number;
```

//first class

```
    second *move = [[second alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
    move.number = 15;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:move animated:YES];
    [move release];
```